# Why does Minecraft on PC keep saying that it can't connect to a server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I have Minecraft on PC and I have donated to this really awesome server that I love but the problem is every time I try to join the server it says "Internet Timed Out."

I have full bars for the connection between me and the server and my internet connection is full. Why can't I connect to the server?

Comment: Try connecting to another server. Does that work?

Comment: yeah, if it works for other servers, I would think you banned from it.

Comment: I can connect to any other server and i am not banned from it because i looked on the servers ban page and i was not on there but thanks for helping anyway!

Comment: Can other people get onto that server?

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons you can't enter into a specific server:

- Server isn't compatible with your minecraft client version.
- You don't have the additional resources the server is using (like for mods and/or fixes)
- Server is down for maintenance.
- It doesn't work anymore (server is old?)
- Last and worst: you've been banned.